# Multiple equations with a large "{" in front: alignment and labelling

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, equations, numbering

I'm trying to get the equation shown in the picture. But i only manage to get 
the following coding. Can anyone help me to label it with numbering like the picture? I tried with `\begin{eqnarray}` or `\begin{equation}` but end up with many errors.

```
\[ \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    \dot {x}_1 = f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n) \\
     \hspace{13pt}   \dots \\
    \dot {x}_n = f_n(x_1,\dots,x_n)  \\
  \end{array}
\right.
\]
```

[image: HELP]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can format TeX code by selecting it and clicking on the `{}` button (or adding four spaces in front of each line). Change `\[` and `\]` into `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}` respectively.

Comment: @Andrew Ooi - Please see the [startup guide](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of inserting a row that starts with three horizontal dots, you could also create a row with a set of *vertical dots* centered on the `=` signs. The code below implements this idea via the `\vdotswithin` macro of the `mathtools` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
       \begin{aligned}
          \dot {x}_1 &= f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n) \\
          &\vdotswithin{=} \\  % vertical dots, centered on the "=" signs
          \dot {x}_n &= f_n(x_1,\dots,x_n)
       \end{aligned} 
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't forget `\!` before `\begin{aligned}`.

Comment: @DonutE.Knot In this case, it's not as necessary as in other cases, since `aligned` is not used inside one logical equation (where you need `\!`), rather it's used as it should be: to align multiple equations inside other math and the `\{` is not part of the equations. Therefore I would advocate here for keeping the extra space.

Answer (score 9):

Try with this code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
        \dot {x}_1 = f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n) \\
        \ldots \\
        \dot {x}_n = f_n(x_1,\dots,x_n)
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

You can also use your code, but with some changes (which egreg said):

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
        \begin{array}{lr}
            \dot {x}_1 = f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n) \\
            \hspace{13pt}   \dots \\
            \dot {x}_n = f_n(x_1,\dots,x_n)  \\
        \end{array}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: `equation` should be used instead of `align`.

Comment: @egreg - Ok, I will change.